# iPhone Chrome changes layout after about 1 second

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, responsive-design

I am experiencing a strange problem with my responsive site on Chrome on an iPhone.

I have developed and tested the site using Chrome desktop's device testing feature. Everything seems to be working fine and the site looks correct as per this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot - good - on Chrome desktop]

When I run the site on my iPhone using Safari, everything still looks fine, as shown on the above image.

However, when I run the same screen on my iPhone using Chrome, it initially loads exactly as shown in the above image, but less than a second later it suddenly changes to look like the image below:
[image]

You can see that some of the elements have been resized and shifted. Everything works fine, but it looks off.

I have no idea what is causing this. I also have no idea how I can examine what is happening on the iPhone Chrome which is not happening in Chrome desktop.

You can find the website at stratnavapp.com if you want to check it out for yourself.

If anyone can give me any clues, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried in iPhone 11 pro max and iPhone 6 it works perfectly also tried to inspect in my chrome desktop browser looks perfect with all sizes, can you try to remove maximum and minimum scales and just keep: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Thanks @MohammedGomaa, I tried that now but the problem remains.

Comment: My device is an iPhone X if that matters. (I shouldn't have thought it would, but who knows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually changed

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

after reading https://web.dev/responsive-web-design-basics/#viewport

That seems to have solved the problem for me.

Comment: Just checking back, I realise that this is exactly what @Mohammed Gomaa had proposed above. I have no idea why it did not seem to work at that time...